# C#: Count distinct values in list of tuples

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to get the total of the same days per studentId. I have converted thet datetime to the day of the week (an int). 
GetAllInfo receives all the needed data from an other class. Then GetTimeExercises uses this data.

Example of the data in the list ExercisesWithTime: (291, 5) (301, 5) (291, 5)

291 is the student id and 5 is day of the week.

Now I want to count all the duplicate values in the list and add the total to a list or dictionary. 
Wanted result: Student id + total days

So for example: (291, 5) (301, 5) (291, 5)  should give (291, 2) (301, 5)

```
private List<Tuple<int, int>> ExcercisesWithTime = new List<Tuple<int, int>>(); 

public void GetAllTimeWithExercises()
{
    GetAllInfo();
    GetTimeExercise(AllStudentInfo);          
} 

private void GetTimeExercise(List<IctLabTable> studentInfo)
{
    foreach (var item in studentInfo)
    {
        ExcercisesWithTime.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(item.StudentId, ConvertDayOfWeek(item.CreatedAt)));                
    }            
}

private int ConvertDayOfWeek(DateTime dateValue)
{
    int dayOfWeek = (int) dateValue.DayOfWeek;

    return dayOfWeek;
}
```

I tried different things, but without success. I tried to solve it with creating a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> StudentDayTotalExercises = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>();

//// Studentid + day (Example: 291 + 5)
private void CountSameDays(List<Tuple<int, int>> xList)
{
    foreach (var item in xList)
    {
        var TotalDays = 1;

        if (!StudentDayTotalExercises.ContainsKey(item.Item1))
        {
            var TupleStudentDays= new Tuple<int, int>(item.Item2, TotalDays );
            StudentDayTotalExercises.Add(item.Item1, TupleStudentDays);
        }

        else
        {
            Here I wanted to increment the value if the key existed. But without success.
            //StudentDayTotalExercises[item.Item1, ]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply group by the `Tuple` and count the occurrences:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> excercisesWithTime = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create(291, 5),
    Tuple.Create(301, 5),
    Tuple.Create(291, 5)
};

// method syntax
var result = excercisesWithTime.GroupBy(key => key, item => 1)
                               .Select(group => new { 
                                   group.Key, 
                                   Duplicates = group.Count() 
                               });

//query syntax
var result = from item in excercisesWithTime
             group 1 by item into g
             select new {
                 g.Key,
                 Duplicates = g.Count()
             };
```

I'd recommend that you create a proper class with properties rather than use `Tuple`s. The use is clearer and you do not need to remember what you placed in each `ItemX` of it.

*If you are working with C# 7.0 see its features regarding to tuples*

Comment: I didn't know syntax "group 1" or "item => 1" instead of "group item" or "item => item". It seem to be exactly the same, you confirm Gilad ? Thank you

Comment: @AFract - It is not the same. Because all is needed is knowing the number of items in the group and the rest of the data is in the `Key` I do not need to store the `item`s in the grouping but it is enough to have an `IEnumerable<int>` - that is why I selected 1

Comment: Ok I got it. It gives exactly the same result at the end, but it avoids to create an intermediate IGrouping with all tuples inside. And you could have used anything else than 1 to achieve this, the final result would have been the same if you had replaced "1" by "potatoes" as only the Count matters. :)